# How to increase the height of UITabBar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm attempting to set the tab bar's height from within `AppDelegate.m`'s. When I create a frame with a taller height and set it to the tabbar, there is a part of the tabbar above it's line that is not clickable, although it does show. (It is the area that shows above the tabbar's shadow gradient image that indicating it's top border). It is clearer when there is a custom background image set.

What is a good way to increase the height of the tabbar(preferably from within app delegate) that wouldn't have any unclickable areas.

The `applicationDidfinishLaunching` method -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Make two View Controllers
    UIViewController* firstVC = [UIViewController new];
    UIViewController* secondVC = [UIViewController new];

    // Make Tab Bar Controller
    UITabBarController* tabBarController = [UITabBarController new];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[firstVC, secondVC]];

    // Set tab's Title & Image
    talksVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First"
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"f"]
                                                         tag:1];

    speakersVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second"
                                                          image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"s"]
                                                            tag:2];

    // Increase height of tab bar
    CGFloat tabBarHeight = 120.0;
    tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                               [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - tabBarHeight,
                                               [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                                               tabBarHeight);

    // [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

    // Load into the Window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Related Questions
[How to increase the size of UITabbar][1]

[Tab Bar with Large Icons][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230128/how-to-increase-the-size-of-uitabbar
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740824/tab-bar-with-large-icons/16742065#16742065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing height is not possible for UITabBar. Alternatively, we could change the Y-Offset of the UITabbar frame. If you reduce the Y-Offset value, then it will automatically adjust the bottom size.

Answer (score 0):

try to create an `UITabBar` category and implement this

```
-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    return CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height + 100);
}
```

and `#import` it.
This works with `UINavigationBar`, i assume it should work with `UITabBar` too

Comment: overriding an instance method in a category is not recommended at all.

Comment: can I get the doc about that ? I haven't seen anybody told me that it not recommended.

Comment: you may read more... anyway: _If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), **the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime**._ source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html, you are welcome.